# Paragraph Matching in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

So I developed some code as part of a larger project.  I came upon a problem with how to match paragraphs, and wasn't sure how to proceed, so I asked on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466890/paragraph-matching-python).  You can find an in-depth description of my problem there if you're curious.

Just to be clear, **I am not reposting the same question here to get an answer.**

I came up with a solution to my own problem, but I'm unsure of limits/pitfalls, and here seems like the perfect place for that.

**The short version on the explanation is this:**  I have two strings, one is the revised version of the other.  I want to generate markups and preserve the paragraph spacing, thus, I need to correlate the list of paragraphs in each, match them, and then mark the remaining as either new or deleted.

So I have a function (`paraMatcher()`) which matches paragraphs and returns a list of tuples as follows:

- `(num1, num2)` means that the best match for revised paragraph `num1` is original paragraph `num2`
- `(num, '+')` means that there is no match for revised paragraph `num`, so it must be new (designated by the `'+'`)
- `(num, '-')` means that no revised paragraph was matched to original paragraph `num` so it must have been deleted (designated by the `'-'`)

So without further adiue, here is my function:

```
def paraMatcher(orParas, revParas):  
    THRESHOLD = 0.75
    matchSet = []
    shifter = 0

    for revPara in revParas:
        print "Checking revPara ", revParas.index(revPara)
        matchTuples = [(difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=orPara,b=revPara).ratio(), orParas.index(orPara)) for orPara in orParas]
        print "MatchTuples: ", matchTuples
        if matchTuples:
            bestMatch = sorted(matchTuples, key = lambda tup: tup[0])[-1]
            print "Best Match: ", bestMatch
            if bestMatch[0] > THRESHOLD:
                orParas.pop(bestMatch[1])
                print orParas
                matchSet.append((revParas.index(revPara), bestMatch[1] + shifter))
                shifter += 1
            else:
                matchSet.append((revParas.index(revPara), "+"))

        print ""
        print "---------------"
        print ""

    if orParas:
        print "++++++++++++++dealing with extra paragraphs++++++++++++++"
        print orParas
        for orPara in orParas:
            matchSet.insert(orParas.index(orPara) + shifter, (orParas.index(orPara) + shifter, "-"))

    return matchSet
```

While I definitely want review of general coding style, etc, here are a few issues that I'm really interested in getting feedback on:

- The function needs to be called with copies of the lists (`paraMatcher(lst1[:], lst2[:])`)
- How might this fail?
- How do I determine an appropriate value for `THRESHOLD`

**Some Extra Notes:**

- I've left the diagnostic printing in there in case any of you want to test it
- Due to other parts of the code, its more convenient that this function take lists of paragraphs as arguments, rather than the strings
- I don't think it matters, but this is 32-bit Python 2.7.6 running on 64-bit Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

A few tips for leaner code:

- Use `enumerate` while iterating when you need the index, to avoid the sequential search and extra verbosity of `orParas.index(orPara)`. For example the last loop becomes

  ```
  for orIndex, orPara in enumerate(orParas):
      matchSet.insert(orIndex + shifter, (orIndex + shifter, "-"))
  ```
- `max(matchTuples)` achieves the same as `sorted(matchTuples, key = lambda tup: tup[0])[-1]` and avoids sorting. You could even give a `key` argument to `max`, but tuples are sorted item by item anyway, and here the second item is an ascending integer, so including it in the sort key does not change the order.
- Unpacking `bestRatio, bestIndex = max(matchTuples)` improves readability as you can use `bestRatio` instead of `bestMatch[0]` in the code that follows.